# force UDP broadcast via the network (disable loopback)

Tags: c, linux, networking, udp, broadcast

I want to send a UDP broadcast datagram to multiple devices on the network, including the sender device itself. The goal is to have all devices receive the data at the EXACT same time (well, +/- 5ms is OK).

The problem is that the network interface on the sending device is looping the data back, so it is received immediately (in contrast to the other devices where network latency comes into play - quite a bit for Wifi for instance)

Any idea how I can disable my network interface to loop the data back directly?

Another idea I had: Is it possible to create a virtual network interface to send the broadcast packet and listen on another interface which only receives it via the network?

I am trying to do that in C on a Linux machine. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you misunderstood how networks work. You can't send a message to yourself, have it wait there in the cable/air for X milliseconds, and then come back. Do you want some target box/router to echo the message back to you? Do you want some sort of delayed loopback interface?

Comment: The broadcast/multicast packets are not actually sent.  They are always queued back in the interface's input queue, so you always get them **before** remote sites.  By the way, you cannot receive the packet at the EXACT same place, as they are in different places, and you have to account for transmission delay, bridging, routing, and several other things that can delay deliveries.  Why did you think 5ms is OK and not 0.5s?  Network bandwiths vary from bps to Gbps (even Tbps, now).

Comment: Better explain what is your **real** problem, not what you have in your head to plan a solution.

Comment: I want to start audio playback on multiple devices in perfect sync. My current solution makes sure all receivers have enough data buffered and I "only" need a start command to be received everywhere at the same time. More than 10ms results in an echo. NTP does not work for me because the clocks on the target devices are not precise enough (cheap hardware).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UDP are sent as IP-payload. The routing of IP packets is a domain of the IP stack. It decides how a packet is transferred to the destination. When you IP stack detects that the destination is the local host it will enqueue the packet in the receive queue and the packet will be available immediatly. If your adapters' send queues are filled that you will have a delay. So you can't make a synchronization with this concept.

If you need a hard synchronization you should utilize NTP or SNTP tro synchronize the clocks and define a comment start time for your desired common operation.

*Edit*:
The (S)NTP protocol is designed to synchronize at millisecond Level. You will get a precision that you can't achieve with any Transmission of UDP packets due to the reason I described above.

Comment: And in linux it's far more feasible to have clocks in synch using NTP and select the proper epoch to begin some process at the same time on several machines.

Comment: NTP does not work in my case. The clocks on the target devices are not precise enough (old & cheap hardware). I need to be in the <10ms range...

Comment: @Daniel can you elaborate what you mean with "not precise". Is the crystal frequenye wrong, is the frequency instable? 32768kHz crystals have usually a better precision than the high frequency crystals of PCs and microcontroller.

Comment: @harper requesting the current time returns a very precise value, but it seems to be only updated every 10ms. Also, the clocks are relatively quickly going out of sync...

Comment: If you have a problem with a 10ms NTP update intervall, how often do you want to send the synchronization packets with UDP? Your crystal has to be sufficient to hold the phase for some milliseonds or ypu should consider using a different hardware.

Comment: @harper I think he means that the resolution of his clocks is only 10ms.

Comment: @ViktorDahl That doesn't match the requirement for a <10ms accuracy.